# symbolを入力とすることは出来ない？

Tags: python, python3, sympy

以下のコードにおいて、inputにtの関数を入れれば動きますので、”symbolを入力とすることは出来る”と言えそうなのですが、typeで型を見ればわかる通り、これはstr扱いです。シンボルとして入力したいのですがどうすれば良いでしょうか

```
import sympy as sp

t=sp.symbols("t")

f=input()
print("f",type(f))

sp.plot(f,(t,1,10))
```

Comment: `f = sp.sympify(input())` として、文字列を sympy の数式に変換すれば良さそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます